# Add two google translate script in a page one for desktop and one for mobile

Tags: jquery, google-translate

I would like to add google translate script for 2 time in a page one for desktop and one for mobiles. I placed the script but it works for only once rather two time.

```
<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
        {pageLanguage: 'en'},
        'google_translate_element'
    );
}
</script>
<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Calling script for desktop in a separate code

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Calling script for mobile in a separate code

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Comment: i dont quite understand. If you have both elements with id=google_... in the same DOM u will have a duplicate id and the script will only initialize on the first occurence

Comment: i want to show the google translator separately for desktop and mobile as my site us responsive I want call script twice so is there ways I can do place the div separetly?